# how do I add callback for new invoice

Tags: magento-1, invoice

Which file do I amend to add a callback function whenever the system is trying to generate new entry in sales_flat_invoice?

Version 1.4.1.1

Comment: Please specify Magento version?

Comment: version 1.4.1.1